# How to fetch url from backend to iframe when change in selection in angular material

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular-material-8

[image]

.html page

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="{{url}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

.ts file

```
 this.url = 'https://www.youtube.com';
```

On change of selection from dropdown list based on the url ifrmae src should get updated.

Answer (score 0):

in .html page

```
<iframe width="100%" class="embed-responsive-item" height="100%" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

in .ts file

```
import ElementRef from '@angular/core';
```

Initialise it in constructor as below

```
constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef)
```

add these lines wherever this you want to get triggered.

```
const iframe = this.hostElement.nativeElement.querySelector('iframe');
iframe.src = 'https://www.youtube.com';
```